# Best to call a template within a template Magento

Tags: magento

So I have been working on a Magento module that hides the price when the user is not logged in. I got it working thanks to @AlanStorm but I just want to make sure it I'm going for the best approach.

What I did is setting a different template for the *catalog_product_price_template* block and from there I did all the logic

```
<?php   $_message = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/pricehideconfig/title'); 
        $_enabled = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/pricehideconfig/active');
        $_current_template = Mage::getBaseDir('design') 
                        . '/frontend/' 
                        . Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName() . '/' 
                        . Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend') .'/'
                        . 'template/catalog/product/price.phtml';

        $_default_template = Mage::getBaseDir('design') . '/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml';
?>

<p>
    <?php if (  $_enabled && !($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) ) { ?>
        <?php echo $_message; ?>
    <?php } else { 

        if (file_exists($_current_template)){ 
            include $_current_template;
        } else{
            include $_default_template;
        }

     } ?>

</p>
```

However, two parts seems really unnatural

1. Calling the 'original' or default template code for the price doesnt feel right, does Magento provides any function to do this, call the default template within a template, while checking if the template exists in the current package and then revert back to the default if none?
2. I think the template should be used for presentation only, so the variables assignment should be moved to a block instead, but i can't really do that since I'm just setting the template and not extending the *Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price_Template*

Comment: Above all, this logic belongs in the block class definition, not in a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the code above !!

if you want to hide price from non-logged in customers the easiest and best way i have used is :

The Module will be Only one Block and the config.xml

Extend - Rewrite class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price

```
class Namespame_ModuleName_Block_Product_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
{
    // and Override _toHtml Function to be 
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
             $this->getProduct()->setCanShowPrice(false);
        }

        if (!$this->getProduct() || $this->getProduct()->getCanShowPrice() === false) {
            return '';
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly without adding more codes to view/template/layout !

If you still want to set Template you can do it also as :

```
class Namespame_ModuleName_Block_Product_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
{
    // and Override _toHtml Function to be 
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
              $this->setTemplate('mymodule/price_template.phtml');
        }

        if (!$this->getProduct() || $this->getProduct()->getCanShowPrice() === false) {
            return '';
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: much simpler and cleaner, thanks, great to see you active on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks bro :) great to see you around also ! long time :)

Comment: Could you please specify how to extend/rewrite the module